# Laravel Echo Server: "Error sending authentication request" on production using HTTPS (Private/Presence channel subscription_error)

Tags: laravel, socket.io, real-time, laravel-echo

I created realtime chat app using: Laravel 5.8, Laravel Echo, Redis, Socket.io and Vue.js.

It works fine on my local machine(localhost). But when I tried to move the app to production server(which has https) - it stopped working and it shows me the next error in laravel-echo-server.log file:

[image: laravel-echo-server.log error]

Also I've changed **laravel-echo-server.json**(echo server config file) like so:

[image: laravel-echo-server.json content]

Also you can see how **window.Echo config** looks like(in app.js):

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

**May be I have some bugs in the configs which mentioned above?**

Also, I think it must be helpful, check the screenshot below what I have noticed in one of client's requests:

[image: client's request error]

I tried to find more information about the error and why it could appear but no results. Exactly I checked laravel log file - it was empty, and nginx error.log file which was empty too, the only place where I saw error it's laravel-echo-server.log file(I shoved its content above)

for additional information you can check what settings I'm using for redis server in my .env file *(I cleared cache when changed .env)*:

```
...

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

...
```

Also, that's what I have in my config/database.php file:

```
...

'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'predis'),
    ],

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 0),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', 1),
    ],

],

...
```

Thank you guys so much for any help, I have been struggling with that problem for the last few days and I can't figure it out, so I will be gratefull for any tips!

Comment: By the way what I've notice is that public channels work fine but Private Channel and Presence Channel don't work (auth arror)

Comment: Do you have the required routes set up in `routes/channels.php` for all of your private and presence channels?

Comment: Hey! thanks but right a few mins ago I've fixed the bug, you can check in the comment below :)

Answer (score 2):

Run This Command In Terminal

`sudo nano /etc/hosts`

Add your project host in Host entry

`127.0.0.1 https://naturalselection.ie`

And Save The File

After Run This Command In Terminal

`laravel-echo-server start`

And enjoy your live Notification With Laravel Echo

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out.

To fix that kind of issue you must go to */etc/hosts* and paste there the next text: 
*127.0.0.1 your_domain_name.com*

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 your_domain_name.com
```

That's all, Hope it will help anybody :)

Comment: Guess you could also have used the local IP address within the `authHost` config of the laravel-echo-server instead. But yeah, normally that's one of the first things you configure when setting up a server, so it's a nice pitfall. :)

Comment: Thanks for resolving this, Taras. In my case I had to use internal docker hostnames instead of the "public" hostname.

Comment: @xyz any chance you can share what you ended up doing? I am having this same issue.

Comment: @janson0 So basically I had the wrong host name in  laravel-echo-server.json. So for my laravel-echo-server docker container (called `npm`) had a links section where I'm mapping the `app` container name to `myfakehostname.local`. And the laravel-echo-server.json authHost points to https://myfakehostname.local